# HtmlUnit button click not submitting

Tags: javascript, forms, button, click, htmlunit

I am trying to click a button in HtmlUnit to login to a site (m.pge.com) but it is not working. The browser stays on same page. I had similar issue with another site. I tried searching but didn't get a definitive answer. 
Any ideas what I might be doing wrong ?

Here is code..

```
    Web_Client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    Web_Client.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    Web_Client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    Web_Client.setJavaScriptTimeout(15000);
    Web_Client.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);

    //Web_Client.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
    // load home page
    HtmlPage page = Web_Client.getPage("https://m.pge.com/#login");
    HtmlTextInput userName = loginForm.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\"usernameField\"]");
    HtmlPasswordInput passWord = loginForm.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\"passwordField\"]");
    userName.setValueAttribute(user);
    passWord.setValueAttribute(password);
    HtmlButton button = null;
    DomNodeList<DomElement> buttonList =  page.getElementsByTagName("button");
    for (Iterator buttonIter = buttonList.iterator(); buttonIter.hasNext();) {
        DomElement domElement = (DomElement) buttonIter.next();
        if(domElement.asText().equals("SIGN IN")) {
            button = (HtmlButton)domElement;
        }
    }

    loginpage = button.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is too tedious and unclear to type in comment so i type it as answer and will update with progress.

Part1: login
The first thing is that are you sure you target the button correctly and where did you initialize the HtmlPage loginpage. Normally, when you assign

```
loginpage = button.click();
```

It will get you the login page,but sometimes it is weird that it doesn't assign new page but rather change the current page. that is your

```
page
```

You may try to print it out before button click and after button click to see if this page changes? that is

```
System.out.println(page.asText());
button.click(); // no need to assign page, if the page changes itself
System.out.println(page.asText());
```

Part2: Search

When you have done input textbox and button click, you will have to target the changes element after search again and get its content, for example, if it is a  element, you should probably target the element after button click and get the content you want afterwards. If you target it before button click, the content in that element won't changes itself, you need to get that again.